# Does/can C++ optimize away call to a function argument?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, function-call, inlining

Let's assume this function template:

```cpp
template <typename F>
void foo(F&& f) {
  f("foo");
}

void to_optimize() {
  foo([](std::string_view s) {
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Does, or can, the compiler optimize the inline function away in cases like this? That is, to replace it effectively with just

```cpp
void to_optimize() {
  std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}
```

?

Comment: See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) - you can look at the compiler-generated asm yourself to see function inlining at work.

Comment: Sure it can. See the [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule.

Comment: If you're interested in what compilers can do have a look at [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) where you can see these kinds of things in action (as in see the generated assembly code). And this would be fun to watch too [what has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4) which is by the author of that site. (Matt Godbolt)

Comment: @PepijnKramer That's really interesting, thanks!

Comment: Very likely that a compiler will inline the call. Because you are passing a lambda by reference rather than a pointer to a function, the call `f("foo");` itself is already a direct call to a specific function, the call operator of the lambda, rather than an indirect call to possibly any function. The compiler will then do its usual inlining analysis and inline the call operator if the inlining criteria are satisfied. It doesn't even need to do anything more sophisticated like determining where `foo` is called. (Although it will probably inline `foo` itself as well.)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard allows any optimization that has no observable effects. As described, optimizing out the function call will have no observable effect. The C++ program has no means of determining whether an additional function call occurred here.

So, yes, a C++ compiler can optimize out the function call. Whether or not it does depends on the compiler and the compiler configuration parameters.

Comment: A mention of the "as-if rule" or a link to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if might improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@PepijnKramer's comment pointed me to where I could explore this myself (with a slighly simplified example) - Clang with `-O2`: https://godbolt.org/z/YEb8vjYev. Indeed the compiler completely optimizes away the function call.

[image]

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#ifdef AS_FUNCTOR
template <typename F>
void foo(F&& f) {
  f(42);
}

void to_optimize() {
  foo([](int s) {
      std::cout << s;
    });
}

#else  // AS_FUNCTOR

void to_optimize() {
  std::cout << 42;
}
#endif  // AS_FUNCTOR
```

Comment: Compiler-explorer has a built-in diff pane.  You can use `#ifdef` and `-Dfoo` vs. `-Ufoo` to make the same source compile to different asm that lines up.

Comment: Your lambda doesn't use its argument, it also uses a hard-coded `42`, so there wasn't even any constant-propagation for the compiler to do after inlining.  BTW, the asm would be simpler if you drop the `std::endl` or at least replace it with `<< '\n'` or `<< "\n"`.  The asm for an explicit flush after outputting a newline is just extra noise, and makes your programs run slower, so stop using `std::endl` when you don't need to flush the stream even if it's redirected to a file.

Comment: @PeterCordes _Compiler-explorer has a built-in diff pane_ Ooooh, nice

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for spotting my error, indeed the lambda was supposed to use the argument. Let me try to fix that and re-post the result.